# Closed form for $\sum_{i = 1}^n i \cos(\beta i)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a closed form solution to the following sum:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n i  \cos(\beta  i)?$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: The answer to the posted question is "Yes, there is a closed-form solution to that sum."

Comment: Hint: What is $\sum_{k=1}^n k z^k$ ? Substitute $z$ by $e^{\beta i}$ and look at the real part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cos(\beta k) = \Re\sum_{k=1}^nk\,(e^{i\beta})^k,$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\,z^k = z\,\frac d{dz}\sum_{k=1}^n z^k = z\,\frac d{dz}\Big(\frac{z(1-z^n)}{1-z}\Big).$$

---

Using the hints above, you should arrive at
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\cos(\beta k) = \frac{(n+1)\cos(n\beta) - n\cos((n+1)\beta)-1}{4\sin^2(\beta/2)}.$$

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! Can we use this technique to obtain a closed form for

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n k \cos\left(\alpha n + \beta k\right)?$$

I tired... but didn't obtain anything useful. Thanks again!

Comment: @user304347 Yes, since that would correspond to $$\Re\Big(e^{i\alpha n}\sum_{k=1}^nk (e^{i\beta})^k\Big) = \frac{(n+1)\cos(n(\alpha+\beta))-n \cos(\beta+n(\alpha+\beta))-\cos(n\alpha)}{4 \sin^2(\beta /2)},$$
which you get by the same technique.

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, I've made a little mistake... now I have the same result.